# SVG nested filter make white transparent

Tags: svg, matrix-multiplication, svg-filters

I am experimenting with a set of noise/static textures. My goal is to create a texture that looks like this: [GOAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rRm5.png)

And I've come pretty far in getting the static texture and applying it over an output of a saturate matrix, for more context see 5th, rightmost strip [here](https://codepen.io/geletina/pen/wvvdeqe)

```
`<filter  x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" id="noiseMatrix3" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" result="f1" stitchTiles="noStitch" baseFrequency="0.2" numOctaves="1" seed="2" />
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
            values="-11 0 0 0 6
                    -11 0 0 0 6
                    -11 0 0 0 6
                    0 0 0 0 1" in="f1" result="f2" />
   <feColorMatrix type="saturate" in="SourceGraphic" values=".6" result="f4"/>
    <feComposite in="f2" in2="f4" result="f5"  operator="arithmetic"  k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0"/>
</filter>`
```

However, in place of the white texture I would like to see the Source image (ie pink gradient in the photo). I suspect it has something to do with converting the white values to alpha. However when I tried filtering the noise with `luminanceToAlpha` first then merging I had to use a different operator and resulting noise did not inherit the color from the saturate filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a multiply rather than an add - this combination of k's work better for your feComposite/arithmetic

```
 <filter  x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" id="noiseMatrix3" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" result="f1" stitchTiles="noStitch" baseFrequency="0.2" numOctaves="1" seed="2" />
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
        values="-11 0 0 0 6
                                    -11 0 0 0 6     
                                    -11 0 0 0 6      
                                    0 0 0 0 1" in="f1" result="f2" />
  <feColorMatrix type="saturate" in="SourceGraphic" values=".6" result="f4"/>
  <feComposite in="f2" in2="f4" result="f5"  operator="arithmetic"  k1="1" k2="0" k3=".6" k4="0" />   

 </filter>
```